# Abysmal Nvidia GPU performance

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have an Asus Laptop with a hybrid GPU (Intel HD 520 & nvidia 940m). On a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the iGPU performs as expected:

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
=======================================================

...

=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 1380 
=======================================================
```

But the nvidia GPU performs poorly

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     nouveau
    GL_RENDERER:   NV118
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
=======================================================

...

=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 292 
=======================================================
```

Even worse performance with the proprietary driver:

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     NVIDIA Corporation
    GL_RENDERER:   GeForce 940M/PCIe/SSE2
    GL_VERSION:    4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116
=======================================================

...

=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 165 
=======================================================
```

The system runs fine if I use the iGPU but lags terribly with the nvidia gpu (firefox becomes a slideshow). Why is this happening?

Comment: My score is `glmark2 Score: 4301` with `NVIDIA 430.34` on `GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2` but I am using `i3` window manager with `compton` compositor. But indeed Your score seems low...

Comment: Have You tried the latest nvidia driver `435.21`?